# Movie Database, multiple genres for each movie (without using movieID)

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I'm trying to improve my old database assignment where I'm building a movie database from provided txt-files. My problem is to build a many to many relation between movies and genres (one movie should be able to have multiple genres).

**TXT files:**
movies.txt : title, year
genres.txt : title, genre, year

Genres.txt contains movies that are not in movies.txt and those movies should not be included in the database. A movie is uniqely identified by its title and year ( so no movieID I guess). This is how I set up the relation:

```
CREATE TABLE `tempGenres` (
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `genre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `year` INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `length` int NULL,
  `year` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (title,year)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `genres` (
  `genre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (genre)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE movie_genre
(
  `genre` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `year` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`genre`, `title`, `year`),
  INDEX `fk_genres_has_movies_movies1_idx` (`title` ASC, `year` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_genres_has_movies_genres1_idx` (`genre` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_genres_has_movies_genres1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`genre`)
    REFERENCES `mdb`.`genres` (`genre`)
    ON DELETE cascade
    ON UPDATE cascade,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_genres_has_movies_movies1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`title` , `year`)
    REFERENCES `mdb`.`movies` (`title` , `year`)
    ON DELETE cascade
    ON UPDATE cascade
) ENGINE INNODB;
```

I have tried importing the data in various ways and changing my relation around but I still get all movies,genres and years from the genres.txt which are not in movies.txt and I don't get multiple genres for those movies that are actually in the movies.txt...

Comment: Your schema looks ok.  How are you importing the data?

Comment: Basically, I would insert the contents of movies.txt into the movies table, insert a distinct set of genres from genres.txt into the genres table, then insert the contents of genres.txt into the movie_genre table, ignoring any rows that don't comply with the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Yeah..movies.txt is loaded into the movies table and genres are loaded with distinct into the genres table resulting in 21 different genres.

But yeah..the trouble is how to insert genres.txt into movie_genre I guess.. tried various ways but how would I ignore rows that don't comply with the foreign key constraint?

Comment: I should maybe mention I have this set:
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

Comment: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1 before inserting into movie_genre, and make sure you use the IGNORE keyword.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have everything in a temp table, you can JOIN with movies and genres to take only matching rows.

Comment: Ok, tried this:
load data local infile "genres.txt" ignore into table movie_genre fields terminated by '\t' (title, genre, year);
But got:
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mdb`.`movie_genre`, CONSTRAINT `fk_genres_has_movies_movies1` FOREIGN KEY (`title`, `year`) REFERENCES `movies` (`title`, `year`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Will try joining instead. Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: Damn..think it works now. Did this:

SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

INSERT IGNORE INTO movie_genre (title,genre,year) SELECT movies.title,tempGenres.genre, movies.year FROM movies INNER JOIN tempGenres ON movies.title = tempGenres.title AND tempGenres.year = movies.year;